# Create file in the application folder from embedded resource Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have stream created from embedded resource:

```
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
```

I can’t create a new file from this stream. I tried several approaches, but sometimes the file is empty, in other situations it is not created at all.

Approach #1 (file not created):

```
var targetFile = new Java.IO.File(targetFilePath);
var buffer = new byte[16345];

using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
using (var fileOutputStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(targetFile))
{
    int read;
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileOutputStream.Write(buffer);
    }
}
```

Approach #2 (file remains empty):

```
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

I would be grateful if you could help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: the application bundle is signed and read-only.  You cannot write to it.  Period.  Android provides other tools for writing files at run time - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

Comment: I want to create a file in the internal storage: /data/user/0/com.***/files/file.txt and according to the documentation application and OS can write to this location. For example EF Core can create SQLite database in this location.

Comment: see the docs about how to build writable file paths

Comment: `and according to the documentation application and OS can write to this location.` Yes, that is possible.

Comment: The file is not empty on my side, you can try to print the length of  `fileStream.Length.ToString()`.